# TypeScript - import - default or not default

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

If I have the following code in `test.ts`:

```
class A {}
class B {}

export A;
export B;

export default {A, B};
```

and I import it like this:

```
import {A, B} from 'test.ts'
```

Which of the following will it do?

- Import the default export, and destructure it into A and B
- Import the named-export A and import the named-export B

And why does it do the one it does?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I believe this question is the same for ES6 modules.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4996

Comment: Thanks @sookie, I always thought you could destructure inside the `import` statement.